# Connection between invariant subspaces and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose map $A: R^n \rightarrow R^n$ has invariant subspaces $L_1,L_2$ such that $\dim (L_1 \cap L_2) = 1$. Does A have real eigenvalue?

The only link between eigenvalues and invariant subspaces I know is that linear span of set of eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue is invariant with respect to A. But I don’t see how it relates to being real?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=L_1\cap L_2$, $X$ is also an invariant subspace isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, so $A$ induces a linear mapping $A':\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.
Then $A'(1)$ is a real eigenvalue of $A$, corresponding to the eigenvector generating $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $L_1\cap L_2$ is also an invariant subspace. Since it is one-dimensional, it is a subspace of an eigenspace.

Comment: So one-dimensional eigenspace cannot correspond to complex eigenvalue?

Comment: Of course not. Every real eigenspace of a real matrix must correspond to a real eigenvalue. Suppose $Ax=\lambda x$, where $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus0$ are real. If $\lambda$ is nonreal, then the LHS ($Ax$) is real but the RHS ($\lambda x$) is nonreal, which is impossible.